# Exporting am chart on server

Tags: grails, itext, amcharts

i am using grails ,
 i need to put [amchart](http://www.amcharts.com/demos/simple-column-chart/) in my pdf(using iText ) report.
 chart is created on browser.
 is there any way . to generate chart as image .
so that i put that chart in my pdf.

Comment: Can you tell us what you have already tried?

Answer (score 0):

There are detailed instructions for how to export a chart as a PDF or image [here](http://www.amcharts.com/tutorials/exporting-charts-and-maps-as-an-image-or-pdf/). There's also [a demo](http://www.amcharts.com/demos/exporting-chart-to-image/) of exporting a chart to an image - click the export button in the top-right corner of the chart, to see it in action.

Comment: i need to export image on server side